# how to pass map values thorugh params in Elasticsearch for partial update?

Tags: elasticsearch

I got a problem when using script in elasticsearch, I have a doc that stored map field, and I want to partial update the doc using scirpt, for normal field I can pass value by using params, but I don't know how to pass params for updating map field, is there any solution for this situation? 
Thank you in advance for any response.

for instance, I have the doc:

```
{
   "_index": "tour-1",
   "_type": "product",
   "_id": "5587375",
   "_version": 1033,
   "found": true,
   "_source": {
      "active": 1,
      "departurePrices": {
          "1": {
             "minPrice": 1000,
             "tradePrice": 800
          },
          "2": {
             "minPrice": 2000,
             "tradePrice": 2500
          }
      }
   }
}
```

for the field active I can pass the value like below script, but the departurePrices field is stored as a map, how can I pass the params to update the value of departurePrices.1.minPrice and departurePrices.1.tradePrice?

```
POST tour-1/product/5587375/_update
{
    "script" : {
        "inline": "ctx._source.active=params.active;",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "active" :1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
POST tour-1/product/5587375/_update
{
    "script" : {
        "inline": "ctx._source.departurePrices[params.mapKey] = params.mapValues;",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "mapKey": "1",
            "mapValues": {
              "minPrice": 990,
              "tradePrice": 850
            }
        }
    }
}
```